# How to remove ticklabels on a histogram with log scale

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram, axis-labels, logarithm

The following code does not remove yticklabels while it should since there is `ax.set_yticklabels([])`.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.random.standard_normal(10)

fig = plt.figure()

ax = plt.axes()

ax.hist(data)
ax.set_yscale('log')

ax.set_yticklabels([])
```

[image]

Note: if changing `10` by `100` in `data = np.random.standard_normal(10)`, the yticklabels are correctly removed...
[image]

- Is this a bug to report? If so, how (and where) to report it?
- Is there another way to remove those yticklabels?

Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can hide like below:

```
ax.axes.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
ax.axes.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
```